# Repeat rows in DataFrame N times based on len(list) in column with different list values

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

I have a DataFrame, which looks like:

```
     col_1    col_2  ...  col_n   date  
1    1        0           1       [[2017-02-01, 2017-12-01]]
2    0        1           1       [[2018-01-01, 2018-01-01], [2019-01-01, 2019-02-01]]
3    1        1           0       [[2018-04-01, 2019-03-01]]
...
n    0        0           1       [[2017-12-01, 2017-12-01], [2018-03-01, 2018-03-01], [2018-05-01, 2018-05-01], [2018-08-01, 2018-12-01]]
```

And I need to repeat columns that's `df.date` have multiple list values and that split them to new columns `df.start_date` and `df.end_date`

e.g.

```
     col_1    col_2  ...  col_n   date_start    date_end 
1    1        0           1       2017-02-01    2017-12-01
2    0        1           1       2018-01-01    2018-01-01
3    0        1           1       2019-01-01    2019-02-01
4    1        1           0       2018-04-01    2019-03-01
...
n    0        0           1       2017-12-01    2017-12-01
n    0        0           1       2018-03-01    2018-03-01
n    0        0           1       2018-05-01    2018-05-01 
n    0        0           1       2018-08-01    2018-12-01
```

I tried

```
date_df['repeat_num'] = [[[row, idx] for idx, item in enumerate(_list)] for row, _list in enumerate(date_df['date'])]

for row in range(len(date_df)):
    if id_tuple[row][0][1] == 1: np.repeat(date_df.values, 1, axis = 0)
    elif id_tuple[row][0][1] == 2: np.repeat(date_df.values, 2, axis = 0)
    elif id_tuple[row][0][1] == 3: np.repeat(date_df.values, 3, axis = 0)
    elif id_tuple[row][0][1] == 4: np.repeat(date_df.values, 4, axis = 0)
    elif id_tuple[row][0][1] == 5: np.repeat(date_df.values, 5, axis = 0)
```

But don't think it worked properly.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) working in pandas 0.25+ and create new columns with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
print (date_df)
   a                                               date
0  4       [[2017-02-01 00:00:00, 2017-03-01 00:00:00]]
1  7  [[2017-02-01 00:00:00, 2017-04-01 00:00:00], [...

df = date_df.explode('date')
print (df)
   a                                        date
0  4  [2017-02-01 00:00:00, 2017-03-01 00:00:00]
1  7  [2017-02-01 00:00:00, 2017-04-01 00:00:00]
1  7  [2017-02-01 00:00:00, 2017-04-01 00:00:00]


df[['date_start','date_end']] = pd.DataFrame(df.pop('date').values.tolist(), index=df.index)
print (df)
   a date_start   date_end
0  4 2017-02-01 2017-03-01
1  7 2017-02-01 2017-04-01
1  7 2017-02-01 2017-04-01
```

EDIT:

Solution for oldier pandas versions:

```
s = date_df.pop('date')
df = date_df.loc[date_df.index.repeat(s.str.len())]
df[['date_start','date_end']] = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(s), index=df.index)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   a date_start   date_end
0  4 2017-02-01 2017-03-01
1  7 2017-02-01 2017-04-01
2  7 2017-02-01 2017-04-01
```

Comment: Wiith ```pd.explode()``` i transform each element of the list into a row with same values, than create 2 columns and delite ```pf.date``` with ```pd.pop()```.
 But how it became splitted by ```date_start``` and ```date_end```?

Comment: @Doppie - added output of `explode` function - it return column filled by pairs with repeated rows, last `DataFrame` constructor  convert lists to 2 columns

Comment: But is there any options except ```pd.explode``` on pandas 0.23?

Comment: @Doppie - Sure, give me some time.